# Find indexes of nonuniform sample with np.random.choice

Tags: numpy, random, indexing

Let's say I have a positions information in the form a two large 1D arrays X and Y. I want to sample non-uniformly positions from these arrays.
I thought I could do this with np.random.choice, but since it only accepts 1D arrays and I cannot do:

> Xsample = np.random.choice(X, n, p)
>
> Ysample = np.random.choice(Y, n, p)

with n number of points in the sample, and p a probability array, since this will sample different points for Xsample and Ysample, I am left with finding a way to obtain the indexes of one sampling. The problem is that there is no guarantee that the numbers in the lists are unique so cannot quite use np.where.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Doh, I can just sample from the indexes.
Here's a working example:

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Y = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15]) 
p = [0.25, 0., 0.5, 0.25] 

sample_idxs = np.random.choice(arange(len(X)), 2, p)
# can also be
# sample_idxs = np.random.choice(len(X), 2, p)
sample_idxs
> array([2, 4])

X[sample_idxs]
> array([3, 5])

Y[sample_idxs]
> array([13, 15])
```

Comment: Should it not be np.random.choice(np.arange(len(X)), 2, p) ?

Comment: Yes, @mgutsche you are right, and I will change my answer for clarity. However, [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) can take the first parameter a as int as well and does arange(a).